# Javascript Discord Bot mention author in output

Tags: javascript, discord.io

I want:

ME (Veak): !voting

Bot: Veak started a vote

How it is:

Me (Veak): !voting

Bot: undefined started a vote

The  code for I used is 'message.author + 'started a vote'

I did try message.author.username but I get an error message saying i haven't defined username.

Code:

```
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {

    if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];

        args = args.splice(1);
        switch(cmd) {

            case 'ping':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'Pong!'
                });
            break;

            case 'voting':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: ':ballot_box: **| ' + message.author + ' started a vote!**'
                });
                break;
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please remove the discord.js tag from the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `discord.io` you want to do

```
bot.sendMessage({
            to: channelID,
            message: ':ballot_box: **| ' + user.username + ' started a vote!**'
        });
```

I would recommend you switching to `discord.js` due to `discord.io` beeing old and unmaintained

Comment: Same problem occured, but I fixed it by switching to discord.js as you suggested. Now message.author is working too. Thanks a lot!